# PMA Rudin Chapter 4 Exercise 3

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

**Question:**
Let f be a continuous real function on a metric space X. Let Z(f) (the zero set of f) be the set of all $p \in X$ at which $f(p) = 0$. Prove that Z(f) is closed.

**My approach to prove the question:** I took a "proof by cases" approach such that I first consider $Z(f) = \emptyset, Z(f) \neq \emptyset $.

However, I struggle to think of a way to generalise all points in Z(f) since depending on what f is, it could be very difficult to prove the result of Z(f) is closed.

Let's say f is a dirac delta function, such that it is zero almost everywhere, except at zero. Remark: By this I have assumed that $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone supply a proof of this question taking account of the possible different continuous functions.

But nevertheless welcome any worthwhile comments and thoughts !

Comment: Is there a definition of continuity that involves closed sets?

Comment: Yeah. There is a relevant post on the same question. But not what I have wanted :( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179555/prob-3-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-the-zero-set-of-a-continuous-real-function-on-a

Comment: You do realize that the Dirac delta is *not* a function? ... Anyhow, why not take a convergent sequence of points in $Z(f)$ and see what happens to the limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prob. 3, Chap. 4, in Baby Rudin: The zero set of a continuous real function on a metric space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179555/prob-3-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-the-zero-set-of-a-continuous-real-function-on-a)

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean by taking convergent sequence of points in Z(f), without knowing what Z(f) could be ? (I said this since I can imagine Z(f) being a collection of singleton sets with measure zero. The other case I can think of is f is constant at 0 within some closed interval).

Answer (score 1):

A subset is closed iff its complement is open. Therefore, proving $Z(f)=\{p\in X|f(p)=0\}$ is closed is equivalent to proving that $Z(f)^\complement=\{p\in X|f(p)\neq 0\}$ is open.

A subset (of a metric space) is open iff there is an open ball inside the subset around every of its points. Take a point $p\in Z(f)^\complement$, then we know $f(p)\neq 0$. Define $\varepsilon:=|f(p)|>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ with:
$$\forall q\in X\colon d(p,q)<\delta\Rightarrow|f(p)-f(q)|<\varepsilon$$
Or written in another form:
$$\forall q\in B_\delta(p)\colon|f(p)-f(q)|<\varepsilon
\Rightarrow f(q)\neq 0
\Rightarrow q\in Z(f)^\complement$$
Therefore $B_\delta(p)\subset Z(f)^\complement$ is an open ball around $p\in Z(f)^\complement$. Therefore $Z(f)^\complement$ is open and therefore $Z(f)$ is closed.

This lemma can be a bit generalized (showing for example you don't even need a metric on $X$ and a topology is sufficient). I love the proof as is uses the diagonal argument of Hausdorff spaces, which is always elegant:

**Lemma**: For topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ with the latter being Hausdorff as well as continuous maps $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$, the subset:
$$A=\{x\in X|f(x)=g(x)\}\subset X$$
is closed.

*Proof*: The map $(f,g)\colon X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ is continous, therefore preimages of closed sets are closed. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal $\Delta_Y=\{(y,y)|y\in Y\}\subset Y$ is closed and its preimage unter $(f,g)$ is exactly $A$. $\square$

Your question is the following special case: $X$ is a metric space, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ (which is Hausdorff), $g=\operatorname{const}_0$ is the constant function (which is always continuous) of the point $0\in\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $A=Z(f)$.

Comment: Much as I love the diagonal technique, this is not an appropriate proof for someone starting out in Rudin, rather than a topology student.

Comment: You are right about that. I will add a simplified argument before the generalization.